# Change navigation bar height on iOS 7 Xcode5

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

How can I change the default height of the Navigation bar in a Navigation Controller?

I've come across "[This](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)" great article:

But this all just style and color and what not for the "NavigationBar".

And just so you know, I mean extend the total height, because the design I'm working on, the Nav Bar is bigger in height.

Comment: You can't change the `UINavigationBar` height. Do you mean extend it to cover the status bar?

Comment: I mean change the total height of the NavBar. I figured it would be almost impossible if I couldn't find anything on it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the height of the nav bar programatically...

[navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];

[image]

becomes this

[image: image2]

Comment: Can you explain this part in a little more detail? I added that line of code, but doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: I added to AppDelegate and it runs, but the nav bar height doesn't change:

    `UINavigationBar *navbar= [[UINavigationBar alloc] init]; 
    [navbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];`

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 Frame starts below the status bar , so y=0 means it will be under the status bar.You should Change to y=20.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
```